# WxPython: Importing wx.lib

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython

I am attempting to import wx.lib when I do

```
import wx
wx.lib
# I get
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'lib'
```

However if I do

```
import wx.lib
wx.lib
```

Why does this happen? I would expect when importing wx it would also import the packages below it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Importing a package does not automatically import sub-packages, unless the package itself do it for you.

- `wx` package only imports `wx._core`. (wxPython 3.0); you need to import `wx.lib` manually.

BTW, `wx/__init__.py` defines [`__all__`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html?highlight=__all__#importing-from-a-package) with `['build', 'lib', ...]`. You can do this:

```
>>> from wx import *  # affected by `__all__`
>>> lib
<module 'wx.lib' from '/usr/lib/.../wx-3.0-gtk2/wx/lib/__init__.pyc'>
```